# Collect configuration properties with Android Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics since a while now and one feature i am really missing is the ability to understand user configuration statistics. So, for example, i have an option that allows the user to select the measurement unit, it can be Metric or Imperial or automatic. Is there any way in Firebase to have a quick overview of the percentages of this option among active users?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a UserProperty to record the user's selection, and create audiences based on their selection.  Then you would be able to view those audiences in the dashboard.  The only caveat there is that once a user is in an audience they will always be considered part of that audience, even if they later don't fit the filter.  So if someone changed their preference from Imperial to Metric they would show up in both audiences.

Comment: Yeah but that will give you the number of users for a single option which its not useful to me, i need a break down of the distribution of the options, so something like 10% of the users selected X, 20% selected Y and the others selected Z. For some settings i have 20/30 possible values. I cant understand why this is not provided out of the box.

Comment: You could get this type of detail using BigQuery in DataStudio, but not currently in the FB dashboard.

Comment: Yeah but that requires a paid subscription to BigQuery

Comment: Depending on the amount of data generated by your app, you may be able to get the information you need from BigQuery [for free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).